# Synchronizing against relaxed atomics

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I have an allocator that does relaxed atomics to track the number of bytes currently allocated. They're just adds and subtracts so I don't need any synchronization between threads other than ensuring the modifications are atomic.

However, I occasionally want to check the number of allocated bytes (e.g. when shutting down the program) and I want to ensure any pending writes are committed. I assume I need a full memory barrier in this case to prevent any previous writes from being moved after the barrier and to prevent the next read from being moved before the barrier.

**The question is:** what is the proper way to ensure the relaxed atomic writes are committed before reading? Is my current code correct? (Assume functions and types map to std library constructs as expected.)

```
void* Allocator::Alloc(size_t bytes, size_t alignment)
{
    void* p = AlignedAlloc(bytes, alignment);
    AtomicFetchAdd(&allocatedBytes, AlignedMsize(p), MemoryOrder::Relaxed);
    return p;
}

void Allocator::Free(void* p)
{
    AtomicFetchSub(&allocatedBytes, AlignedMsize(p), MemoryOrder::Relaxed);
    AlignedFree(p);
}

size_t Allocator::GetAllocatedBytes()
{
    AtomicThreadFence(MemoryOrder::AcqRel);
    return AtomicLoad(&allocatedBytes, MemoryOrder::Relaxed);
}
```

And some type definitions for context

```
enum struct MemoryOrder
{
    Relaxed = 0,
    Consume = 1,
    Acquire = 2,
    Release = 3,
    AcqRel = 4,
    SeqCst = 5,
};

struct Allocator
{
    void*  Alloc            (size_t bytes, size_t alignment);
    void   Free             (void* p);
    size_t GetAllocatedBytes();

    Atomic<size_t> allocatedBytes = { 0 };
};
```

I don't want to simply default to sequential consistency as I'm trying to understand memory ordering better.

The part that's really tripping me up is that in the standard under `[atomics.fences]` all the points talk about an acquire fence/atomic op synchronizing with a release fence/atomic op. It's entirely opaque to me whether an acquire fence/atomic op will synchronize with a relaxed atomic op on another thread. If an AcqRel fence function literally maps to an mfence instruction, it seems that the above code will be fine. However, I'm having a hard time convincing myself the standard guarantees this. Namely,

> 4 An atomic operation A that is a release operation on an atomic
>   object M synchronizes with an acquire fence B if there exists some
>   atomic operation X on M such that X is sequenced before B and reads
>   the value written by A or a value written by any side eﬀect in the
>   release sequence headed by A.

This seems to make it clear that the fence will not synchronize with the relaxed atomic writes. On the other hand, a full fence is both a release and an acquire fence, so it should synchronize with itself, right?

> 2 A release fence A synchronizes with an acquire fence B if there
>   exist atomic operations X and Y, both operating on some atomic object
>   M, such that A is sequenced before X, X modifies M, Y is sequenced
>   before B, and Y reads the value written by X or a value written by any
>   side eﬀect in the hypothetical release sequence X would head if it
>   were a release operation.

The scenario described is

- Unsequenced writes
- A release fence
- X atomic write
- Y atomic read
- B acquire fence
- Unsequenced reads (unsequenced writes will be visible here)

However, in my case I don't have the atomic write + atomic read as a signal between the threads and the release fence happens with the acquire fence on thread B. So what's actually happening is

- Unsequenced writes
- A release fence
- B acquire fence
- Unsequenced reads

Clearly if the fence executes before an unsequenced write begins it's a race and all bets are off. But it seems to me that if the fence executes after an unsequenced write begins but before it is committed it will be forced to finish before the unsequenced reads. This is exactly that I want, but I can't glean whether this is *guaranteed* by the standard.

Comment: "I don't want to simply default to sequential consistency" - In this case, *I* would. Since that would give me the guarantee needed and the cost is likely to be negligible/unnoticeable and I wouldn't trust myself to get the more clever stuff correct for all cases (and I really, *really* hate debugging subtle threading bugs that only reproduce once in a blue moon and only on customers production systems at 3 o'clock at night when they are doing something important/expensive).

Comment: Sure. But the entire point here is to gain understanding.

Comment: I understand that (and upvoted your question because I think it's really interresting and relevant to know). I was simply giving you *my* pragmatic perspective (in a comment).

Comment: @JesperJuhl What stronger guarantee would sequential consistency give you in this case ?  there is no way you can tell whether the loaded value reflects the latest memory state since runtime synchronization is missing.

Comment: I think he's referring to making the operations on allocatedBytes SeqCst and dropping the fence. If they were then every read and write would be synchronized.

Comment: If all you need is the total memory allocated at program shut down, you just have to read the value after all spawned threads have been joined.

Comment: Apart from joining all the threads the only solution to get what you want is to lock all the threads but not the one that read the allocated memory. A full memory barrier will not help you, because anything could happen just after this barrier executed (thread preemption etc...) and all bet would be off!

Comment: Shutdown is an example, but the question is not limited to that scenario. The question is about synchronizing relaxed writes before a read. I struggling to see how preemption is relevant when the goal is 'ensure already executed writes are globally visible before I do this read'. Thread preemption won't somehow undo a write, nor will any other operation I'm aware of.

Comment: Your expression "synchronizing relaxed writes before a read" gives me doubt about what you are looking for.

Comment: @JesperJuhl LWimsey is right, strengthening the individual operations to `SeqCst` won't change the way this example behaves. The example is already thread safe and free of C++ "data races" (assuming the allocator is internally safe). Confusion is arising because Adam is considering scenarios where the calls to Allocator are racing with each other, then trying to reason about them as if they are ordered.

Comment: @Adam I've worked on many games where we did exactly this: reading the number of allocated bytes while there are still concurrent `Alloc()`/`Free()` happening in other threads. Usually we did this because we just wanted to print the number on-screen, log it, or draw it on a graph. None of these values were guaranteed to be the "latest" (again, there's no such thing as "latest" unless the writers are synchronized with the reader) and in practice, the values could only be a few dozen cycles "old" which is really nothing. We still got meaningful values and that was good enough.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you spawn Thread A, which calls `Allocator::Alloc()`, then immediately spawn Thread B, which calls `Allocator::GetAllocatedBytes()`. Those two `Allocator` calls are now running concurrently. You don't know which one will actually happen first, because there's no ordering between them. Your only guarantee is that either Thread B will see the value of `allocatedBytes` before Thread A modifies it, or it will see the value of `allocatedBytes` after Thread A modifies it. You won't know which value Thread B saw until after `GetAllocatedBytes()` returns. (At least Thread B won't see a totally garbage value for `allocatedBytes`, because there's no data race on it thanks to your use of relaxed atomics.)

You seem to be concerned about the case where Thread A got as far as `AtomicFetchAdd()`, but for some reason, the change is not visible when Thread B calls `AtomicLoad()`. But so what? That's no different from the outcome where `GetAllocatedBytes()` runs entirely before `AtomicFetchAdd()`. And that's a totally valid outcome. Remember, either Thread B sees the modified value, or it doesn't.

Even if you change all the atomic operations/fences to `MemoryOrder::SeqCst`, it won't make any difference. In the scenario I described, Thread B can still either see the modified value or the unmodified value of `allocatedBytes`, because the two `Allocator` calls run concurrently.

As long as you insist on calling `GetAllocatedBytes()` while other threads are still calling `Alloc()` and `Free()`, that's really the most you can expect. If you want to get a more "accurate" value, just don't allow any concurrent calls to `Alloc()`/`Free()` while `GetAllocatedBytes()` is running! For example, if the program is shutting down, just join all the other threads before calling `GetAllocatedBytes()`. That'll give you an accurate number of allocated bytes at shutdown. The C++ standard even guarantees it, because [the completion of a thread synchronizes with the call to join()](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.threads#thread.thread.member-4).

Comment: The situation I'm concerned about is this: let's say that Thread B *knows* Thread A has executed the relaxed atomic sub. B then calls `GetAllocatedBytes()`. Is it possible B will read the value of `allocatedBytes` *before* the write is globally visible? Can the write still be in the other cores store buffer for example?

Comment: @Adam How willl thread B know A executed Alloc? You need a synchronization for that. And at this point it makes sense to use a mutex, atomic fence or just one atomic variable with release and (in B) aquire. Then you can make sure you get the right value.

Comment: It is totally impossible for Thread B to know that Thread A has executed the relaxed atomic *unless* some information is communicated between threads that confirms it. It could be joining the thread, it could be a separate atomic guard variable (not seen in your example), or it could be communicated by mutex/condition variable. The nice thing is that every mechanism for *really* knowing that the atomic write took place also permits you to establish a "synchronizes with" relationship between threads if done correctly http://preshing.com/20130823/the-synchronizes-with-relation/

Answer (score 0):

This will not work properly, `acq_rel` memory order is designed specifically for CAS and FAA memory operations that "simulanously" read and write atomic data. In Your case You want to enforce memory synchronization before load. To do this You need to change memory order of You `fetchAndAdd` and `fetchAndSub` to `acq_rel` and Your load to `acquire`. This may seem much, but on x86 it has very little cost (some compiler optimizations) as it does not generate any new instructions into the code. As of how acquire-release synchronization works I recomend this article: http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

I removed info about sequential ordering as it should be used for all the operations to work properly and would be an overkill.

From my understanding of C++ atomics relaxed memory order makes sense when used in combination with other atomic operations using memory fences. For example in some situations atomic `a` may be stored in relaxed manner, as atomic `b` is written with release memory order and so on.

Comment: This does not work since you need a runtime relationship (that observes the modified value) in order to do something useful. Only making memory ordering stronger is not enough

Comment: What will the CPU do differently in case 1? We have a situation where there may be buffered stores on Core 1. Core 0 comes along and says "everyone flush your store buffers, I have an important read". But is there a way for Core 0 to even do this? ARM gcc 7.2.1 generates the same `__sync_synchronize` for both AcqRel and SeqCst https://godbolt.org/z/zL8MI-. x86-64 generates mfence in both cases. Each of these instructions appear to only operate on the single core that executes it.

Comment: Thanks for information, I'll reconsider my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is *what is the proper way to ensure the relaxed atomic writes are committed before reading* this same atomic object? Nothing, this is ensured by the language, [intro.multithread]:

> All modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some particular total order, called the *modification order* of M.

All threads see the same *modification order*. For exemple imagine that 2 allocation happens in 2 different threads and then you read the counter in a third thread.

In the first thread, the atomic is incremented by 1 bytes, and the relaxed read/modify (AtomicFetchAdd) expression return 0: the counter made this transition: 0->1.

In the second thread, the atomic is incremented by 2 bytes, and the relaxed read/modify expression return 1: the counter make this transition: 1->3. There is no way the read/modify expression return 0. This thread cannot see a transition 0->2 because the other thread has performed the transition 0->1.

Then in a third thread you perform a relaxed load. The only possible values that may be loaded are 0,1 or 3. It is not possible to load 2. The modification order of the atomic is 0 -> 1 -> 3. And the observer thread will also see this modification order.

Comment: This is what I mean by "at least Thread B won't see a totally garbage value" in my answer. As you've said, it'll see one of the values in the modification order of `allocatedBytes`. However, there is no guarantee that Thread B will see the "latest" value because, if `allocatedBytes` is being modified concurrently, the concept of "latest" doesn't even exist. If we want there to be a concept of a "latest" value, there needs to be some synchronization performed elsewhere.

Comment: @preshing I agree with you. I don't think the aim is about the best answer, but for now this is comprehending what he is actualy asking. Its question is so weird, according to my knowledge it does not make sense... because he does not know something fundamental. So I have thought that maybe what he was trying  to ensure that their is a single total order for its atomic counter because he would not known this is also guaranteed with relaxed atomic operation.

Comment: @preshing Like a relativistic world, there is *no global time and no one correct clock*!